# I'm getting a BIOS error when trying to install Ubuntu on Dell G5 15SE 5505 with bootable USB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, bios

This is my second attempt to ask a question in this forum.

I'm currently trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.5 on my computer through a bootable USB. I'm using Rufus to install the Linux ISO with a MBR partition scheme with Target System of Bios or UEFI and a FAT32 File System. When I try to boot Ubuntu via the USB in the BIOS (v 1.5.0) and click on the option "Try Ubuntu without installing" it pops this error screen and after a few seconds it reboots Windows and shows the normal log in screen. Currently, I disabled Secure Mode Boot, but it doesn't seem to work.

The error the pops on the screen is the following: ACPI BIOS Error (Bug):

```
Could not resolve symbol ... AE_NOT_FOUND, ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog, AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter
```

[Picture of the Error in Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUbzQ.jpg)

Has anyone faced this type of error before? Or do you have any idea on how to solve it?

Details of my Laptop:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 4800
- GPU: Radeon RX 5600M
- RAM: 16 Gb
- Space: 1.5 Tb